# How to parse the response header to a variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to parse the response header to a variable in JMeter using regex.

Below is the sample snippet of headers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Add an Post Processor (*Regular Expression extractor*) like below.
[image]

2) Write the condition like below snippet.

[image]

3) Print the value for your reference in a Bean Shell Sampler

${resp_header}

```
sample print snippet for reference.
```

[image]